# How to Create a Newsfeed (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users who follow projects.  Projects have blog posts.

My goal is to aggregate blog posts on the projects that a user follows and list it by most recent.  Right now, I am only able to list all the blog posts of one project before listing the blog posts of the next project, and so on.  Is there a simple way to fix it so that it lists all the blog posts by all projects by most recent?

**user.rb**

```
has_many :projects
scope :newest, order("created_at desc")
```

**project.rb**

```
has_many :blogposts, :dependent => :destroy
```

**blogpost.rb**

```
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
scope :newest, order("created_at desc")
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @user = User.find_by_permalink(params[:permalink])
    @projectsfollowed = @user.followed_projects.newest.page(params[:projectsfollowed_page]).per_page(10)
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @projectsfollowed.each do |project| %>
  <% project.blogposts.newest.each do |blogpost| %>
    <%= render blogpost %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

***UPDATE***
I have been trying to use an Array in my controller but I cannot get it to list out by most recent, along with pagination. Please see below:

```
  blogids = Array.new
  @projectsfollowed.each do |project|
    project.blogposts.each do |blogpost|
      blogids.push(blogpost[:blogpost.id])
    end
  end

  @blog_posts = Blogpost.find(blogids)
```

updated show.html.erb

```
<% @blog_posts.each do |blogpost| %>
    <%= render blogpost %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm confused by your code, why do you have the `newest` scope in your `Project` model, yet your calling it on blogposts?

Comment: I updated it to make more sense. It is used for other parts of my app.

Comment: Note if you use `scope` you mostly want to use `lambda` for the expression afterwards, so the code gets executed everytime you access the scope and not only when loading the class. So `scope :newest, order("created_at desc")` is most likely not what you want. The correct version would be: `scope :newest, lambda { order("created_at desc") }`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638072/1562296

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@blog_posts BlogPost.where(:project_id => @user.followed_projects.map {|p| p.id})
@blog_posts = @blog_posts.order("created_at desc")
```

Comment: @spl Your array update won't work because you can't paginate or order an array. The syntax I provided returns an ActiveRecord Array so you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: When I use your @blog_posts suggestion in my controller and call it in my view, nothing appears. Do you know why?

Comment: What happens when you call `@user.project_ids` (where @user is an actual user) in your console? You should see an array of ids returned if the given user has projects associated with them. Also in my example I made the assumption that your BlogPost model had a `project_id` column.

Comment: user.project_ids calls projects that belongs to user. But I am looking to aggregate blogposts made by projects that the user is following, not necessarily of just projects the user created. Thus, if you see above, I have a @projectsfollowed

Answer (score 1):

You can make "has_many through" association between Users and Blogposts:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :blogposts, :through => :projects
```

Then in your **users_controller.rb** simply do this:

```
@blogposts = @user.blogposts.newest
```

So your view **show.html.erb** can look like:

```
<% @blogposts.each do |blogpost| %>
    <%= render blogpost %>
<% end %>
```

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is more information about "has_many through" association.

Comment: Thanks. But my user.rb already has_many :blogposts because of blogposts he makes for specific projects.  Would this create a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/87-generating-rss-feeds

just need to introduce a separate view for rss feed.